# PHP script don't run in browser

Tags: php

I have simple counter php script, it works well in console but when I  run it on browser, it doesn't work.

```
<?php

if(file_exists('count_file.txt'))   
{
    $fd=fopen('count_file.txt','r');
    $count=fread($fd,filesize('count_file.txt'));
    $count=$count+1;
    echo "count= $count";
    fclose($fd);
    $fd=fopen('count_file.txt','w');
    fwrite($fd,$count);
    fclose($fd);
}
else
{
    $fd=fopen('count_file.txt','w');
    fwrite($fd,1);
    fclose($fd);
}
?>
```

I run this script in terminal by `php filename.php`, it display value of variable **count** increased by each time I run file. But when I run file on browser and F5 or enter address bar again, the value of variable **count**  doesn't increase

So why this script doesn't run on browser?
Thanks for reading

Comment: when you run the file in the browser, are you sure the file `count_file.txt` is being written? it could be a permissions issue.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the begin for showing all warnings/errors.

Comment: Try using `fgets();` instead of `fread();` - you only want the first line anyway. If you are expecting it to create a file in the folder where the script lives then you may need to give the folder chmod 757 permissions or at least the file 646 if you uploaded it and it was not created by the server itself from your script.

Comment: thanks guys, I changed permission for count_file.txt to 7-5-7 and it works well.